# Get list from database using ActiveAndroid

Tags: android, sqlite, activeandroid

New to ActiveAndroid (and overall to android database). I read their documentation, but i have one problem.

I have Route.class and LatLngPosition.class. The Route is made of more LatLngPosition nodes.

So my implementation is:

```
@Table(name="Route")
public class Route extends Model {

@Column(name="Name")
private String name;
@Column(name="Time")
private MyTime time;


public Route(String name, MyTime time) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.time = time;
}

public Route(){
    super();
}

public List<LatLngPosition> getLatLngList(){
    return getMany(LatLngPosition.class, "Route");
}
...
}
```

And my LatLngPosition class:

```
@Table(name="LatLng")
public class LatLngPosition extends Model {
@Column(name = "Latitude")
double latitude;
@Column(name = "Longitude")
double longitude;
@Column(name = "Route", onUpdate = Column.ForeignKeyAction.CASCADE, onDelete = Column.ForeignKeyAction.CASCADE)
Route route;

public LatLngPosition(double latitude, double longitude, Route route) {
    super();
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.route = route;
}
public LatLngPosition(){
    super();
}
...
}
```

I save some data to test if everything works:

```
route1 = new Route("first", new MyTime(1,1,10,10));
LatLngPosition pos1 = new LatLngPosition(10,10, route1);
LatLngPosition pos2 = new LatLngPosition(10,15, route1);
pos1.save();
pos2.save();
route1.save();
```

And then why trying to get it back from database:

```
Route route = Route.load(Route.class, 1);
```

I can call `route.getName()`, and it will return name properly. But when i call `route.getLatLngList()`, i get nothing, size of list is 0.

Why this don't work? Am I implementing right way 1-N relation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may seem a bit dumb but... have you tried saving (inserting) the route before using it with the other class? I'm guessing that when you do the insert it's when the class gets its id which could be used as foreign key in other classes.

`route1 = new Route("first", new MyTime(1,1,10,10));
    route1.save();
    LatLngPosition pos1 = new LatLngPosition(10,10, route1);
    LatLngPosition pos2 = new LatLngPosition(10,15, route1);
    pos1.save();
    pos2.save();`

On a side note: you do realize that with this model you couldn't have intersecting routes, do you?

Comment: I solved this problem, and i always come back and put solution, but i forgot about this one. Yes, that was indeed the problem, position contains reference to route (foreign key), so i had to save route first. I don't know how you found this question, but i will accept your answer. I finished that project it is working well (although Location Services do not record accurate as i though)

Comment: I seem to have a knack for researches that lead me to lowly voted questions here ;P